# GoolgleDrive Authentication in windows service

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, windows-services, google-api-dotnet-client

I am creating Windows service and try to authenticate Google Drive using following code. It works fine in console application, but doesn't work in windows service. Breakpoint leaves control at "GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsyn" method.

```
 using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }
```

Comment: Make sure that what ever account you are running the windows service on has access to your credPath directory

Comment: Yeah, I have checked that path is correct. The .credential directory is created but token file not generated.

Comment: That's not what I am saying.  When you install the windows service it runs under a user.  That user needs to have access to that directory.   Right click the service go to the logon tab.  If its local system account it may not have access.   Set it to a specific account that does have access.

Comment: @DaImTo I have changed account, now it throws an error like "Access Denied".

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you so much...Its Work. I Remove FileDataStore(credPath, true) second parameter true and its Work !!!